# How to set the DirectoryIndex on a tomcat Apache server to serve website?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, apache2

I am using an Apache Tomcat server, that I want to host my website on.

I have copied the contents of my website to /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT, however when I go to the homepage, I am displayed with an error:

[image]

How do I set the DirectoryIndex to point to my root html page?

I realize that I can rename the DirectoryIndex to `index.psp`, however I would rather overwrite the DirectoryIndex.

Comment: Just out of curiosity .. your website is a Java application?

Comment: No, it's just html css application.

Comment: Well, tomcat is a Java application server. You probably want to use just Apache instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/) is a Java application server. If you only want to serve HTML and CSS files you are better off with [Apache HTTP](https://httpd.apache.org/) server (or lighttpd, or nginx, or any other HTTP server).